# How to parse IP address blocks IPv4 / IPv6

Tags: c++, ip-address

I am creating an IP address class wrapper, and I want to differentiate the address types according to [RFC 5735 Section 4 - Special Use IPv4 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-4).

I want to

- be able to test whether an address is within one of the blocks.
- expand a block, so I get an array of IPAddress objects when returning.

If someone can help me by small sample code, or point me to existing code, I'd appreciate that. Sadly I find my brain can't wrap itself around the intricacy of this topic, that's why I am specifically asking for sample code. I know it's not polite to ask for source code like this, and I apologize.

Comment: Have you tried something at least ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coming up with a unified IP address representation, it is important to realize that IPv4 addresses occupy 4 bytes and IPv6 addresses require 16 bytes. A naive wrapper implementation would use a union plus an enum discriminator to indicate the address type. Fortunately, this is not necessary because there exists an unambiguous representation of an IPv4 address *within* an IPv6 address. Keeping this in mind, your IP address wrapper class could look like this:

```
class address
{
  /// Top 96 bits of v4-mapped-addr.
  static std::array<uint8_t, 12> const v4_mapped_prefix =
    {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xff, 0xff }};

public:
  address() = default;

  bool is_v4() const
  {
    return std::memcmp(&bytes_, &v4_mapped_prefix, 12) == 0;
  }

private:
  std::array<uint8_t, 16> bytes_;
};
```

Now to check whether you have a certain class of addresses, you can add member functions ad libitum. Here are examples for loopback, broadcast, and multicast:

```
bool is_loopback() const
{
  if (is_v4())
    return bytes_[12] == 127;
  else
    return ((bytes_[0] == 0) && (bytes_[1] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[2] == 0) && (bytes_[3] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[4] == 0) && (bytes_[5] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[6] == 0) && (bytes_[7] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[8] == 0) && (bytes_[9] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[10] == 0) && (bytes_[11] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[12] == 0) && (bytes_[13] == 0) &&
            (bytes_[14] == 0) && (bytes_[15] == 1));
}

bool is_broadcast() const
{
  return is_v4() &&
    bytes_[12] == 0xff && bytes_[13] == 0xff &&
    bytes_[14] == 0xff && bytes_[15] == 0xff;
}

bool is_multicast() const
{
  return is_v4() ? bytes_[12] == 224 : bytes_[0] == 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just enough to get my brain working, thanks!